# Java get File from enum class

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to get the `File` from enum in Java, like whenever I type `DBIO.DBFOLDER`, it should translate to a File i specified. Is there any way to do so?

```java
package test.Test;

import java.io.File;

public enum DBIO{
    DBFOLDER(),DBFILE();
    public File DBFOLDER(){
        return new File("project/DBFolder");
    }
    public File DBFILE(){
        return new File(DBFOLDER()+"/DBFile");
    }
}
```

Above code doesn't work; I just made it to show what I want it to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd use a `enum` for this use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd be using a `enum` for this use case, but, you need to associate a value with each `enum` case, for example...

```
public enum DBIO {
    DBFOLDER(new File("project/DBFolder")), DBFILE(new File(DBIO.DBFOLDER.getPath(), "DBFile"));

    private File file;
    
    private DBIO(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    
    public File getPath() {
        return file;
    }
    
}
```

So if you were to do something like...

```
System.out.println(DBIO.DBFOLDER.getPath());
System.out.println(DBIO.DBFILE.getPath());
```

It would print...

```
project/DBFolder
project/DBFolder/DBFile
```

Comment: This is possible because an `enum` is a full-blown object rather than some named integer.

Comment: @MCEmperor and that's part of why enums are so powerful on Java compared to other, non-JVM languages. Being able to enumerate a set of values is only the main things Java enums can do. Attaching fields and methods to the enum object allows it to become more useful over time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the valueOf() method to get the Enum value that corresponds to a given String. If you want to get the File associated with an Enum, you will need to store the File as a field in the Enum class and provide a getter method to access it.

Here is an example of an Enum class that stores a File and provides a getter method to access it:

```
public enum FileEnum {
    FILE_1("file1.txt", new File("file1.txt")),
    FILE_2("file2.txt", new File("file2.txt"));

    private final String name;
    private final File file;

    FileEnum(String name, File file) {
        this.name = name;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

You can then use the getter method to access the file associated with the Enum, like this

```
File file = FileEnum.FILE_1.getFile();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```java
import java.io.File;

interface Get< T > {
    T get();
}

enum DBio {
    DBFOLDER( new Get< File >() {
        public File get() {
            return new File( "project/DBFolder" );
        }
    } ),

    DBFILE( new Get< File >() {
        public File get() {
            return new File( DBio.DBFOLDER.get() + "/DBFile" );
        }
    } );

    private Get< File > fileLoader;

    DBio( Get< File > fileLoader ) {
        this.fileLoader = fileLoader;
    }

    public File get() {
        return this.fileLoader.get();
    }

    public File DBFOLDER() {
        return new File( "project/DBFolder" );
    }

    public File DBFILE() {
        return new File( DBFOLDER() + "/DBFile" );
    }
}
```

We use the anonymous class of the Get interface to load the file only when requested.

If we pass directly, the file will be loaded once and kept in memory, always sharing a reference.

You could replace the anonymous class with a lambda:

```java
// ... rest of code equals

DBFOLDER(() -> new File( "project/DBFolder" )),
DBFILE(() -> new File( DBio.DBFOLDER.get() + "/DBFile" ))

// ... rest of code equals
```

Comment: _to load the file only when requested._ - A File object is a light wrapper. It contains.. a string. That is all. It is not a file handle. This hullabaloo with a `Get<T>` interface is pointless overengineering. `=>` is not how you write lambdas in java.

Comment: Thans for the information about the File class and my confusion in the lambda function sintax. I ended up confusiong the syntax with the JS/TS arrow function